# How can I access a assets (animation sequence) using scripting in Spark AR studio

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to change the current frame of an animation sequence using a script in JS
and I can't find the equivalent of `Scene.root.find....` of assets...
I'm trying to create a "Which ____ are you?" and I make the code for the roll an image but I don't know how to access it using scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, this will help you.

```js
const Materials = require('Materials');
const mat = Materials.get('matName');
// set your number here, or an animation
mat.diffuse.currentFrame = 1;
```

UPD 8 May 2021:
Now you should use async methods:

```
const M = require("Materials"); 
const D = require("Diagnostics");
(async function () {
    const mat = await M.findFirst("material0");
    const diff = await mat.getDiffuse();
    diff.currentFrame = 1;
})();
```

Comment: Seems like this approach no longer works.

Comment: @AugustBjornberg Yes, the API changed a lot.